# Timer start and pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have a script that is for a timer. I am not sure how to create a start button. Right now it starts immediately when the page loads. Also the pause button doesn't work.

Here is a fiddle I created for it...

https://jsfiddle.net/c6nqt9uy/

Then is there anyway to output text after the timer has expired like:

Time is up!

For some reason the fiddle is not showing the Resume button when you press pause, but the pause button does nothing anyways.

```
function stopwatch(btn) {
    if (btn.value == "Pause")  {
        clearInterval(ticker);
        btn.value = "Resume";
    } else {
```

Comment: what is that dropdown for?

Comment: To allow more than one time to be used.

Comment: So right now you want a button which starts and stops the timer right?

Comment: Ideally a start, pause, then the pause turns into a resume once pressed, and a reset. Then once the timer has expired text to display saying the time has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<button onClick="StartTimer()">Start</button>

function StartTimer() {
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code did not seem to be behaving properly on jsfiddle, so I downloaded it to my local machine. I found that the timer works, pause/resume button works as well.

Changes I made :

1. I removed the onchange event from select tag
2. I changed the value of button to "Start"
3. I altered the stopwatch() function to this :

   ```
   function stopwatch(btn){
       if (btn.value == "Start"){
           start();
           btn.value = "Pause";
       }
       else if (btn.value == "Pause"){
           clearInterval(ticker);
           btn.value = "Resume";
       } 
       else {
           ticker = setInterval(tick,1000);
           btn.value = "Pause";
       }
   }
   ```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I noticed that I made a mistake. I forgot to include jquery. Now I did. Here is fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/czav0Leg/1/

Select a value from dropdown and click Start

Comment: PS. There are two places for displaying timer. #timer & #countdown. I don't know why. My code only affects #countdown.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;
var start_time;
function Countdown(start) {
    this.start_time = start === undefined ? "1:00" : start ;
    this.target_id = "#timer";
    this.name = "timer";
    start_time = this.start_time;
}

Countdown.prototype.init = function () {
    this.reset();
    ticker = setInterval(this.name + '.tick()', 1000);
}

Countdown.prototype.reset = function () {
    time = this.start_time.split(":");
    this.minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
    this.seconds = parseInt(time[1]);
    this.update_target();
}

Countdown.prototype.tick = function () {
    if (this.seconds > 0 || this.minutes > 0) {
        if (this.seconds == 0) {
            this.minutes = this.minutes - 1;
            this.seconds = 59
        } else {
            this.seconds = this.seconds - 1;
        }
    }
    this.update_target()
}

Countdown.prototype.update_target = function () {
    seconds = this.seconds;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    $(this.target_id).val(this.minutes + ":" + seconds)
}


var timer = new Countdown();
timer.init();


function start() {
    var s = document.getElementById("period").value;
    document.getElementById("period").disabled = true;
    startTimer(s);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
    timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
    document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "black";
    clearInterval(ticker);

    ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
    tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
        showTime(secs);
    } else {
        timeInSecs--;
        document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "You have exceeded your time by " + (hhmmss(Math.abs(timeInSecs)));
        document.getElementById("period").disabled = false;
    }
}

function showTime(secs) {
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    secs %= 3600;
    var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    secs %= 60;
    var result = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + ":" + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = result;
}

function stopwatch(btn) {
    if (btn.value == "Pause") {
        clearInterval(ticker);
        btn.value = "Resume";
    } else {
        btn.value = "Pause"
        var timer = new Countdown($('#timer').val());
        timer.init();
    }
}

function hhmmss(secs) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var mns = Math.floor(secs / 60) % 60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    if (hrs < 10) hrs = "0" + hrs;
    if (mns < 10) mns = "0" + mns;
    if (secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;
    return mns + " minutes " + secs + " seconds";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="timer">
<select id="period" onchange="start()">
    <option value="0">Select time required</option>
    <option value="30">30 Seconds</option>
    <option value="60">1 Minute</option>
    <option value="300">5 Minutes</option>
    <option value="900">15 minutes</option>
    <option value="1800">30 minutes</option>
    <option value="2700">45 minutes</option>
    <option value="3600">60 minutes</option>
    <option value="4500">75 minutes</option>
    <option value="5400">90 minutes</option>
    <option value="6300">105 minutes</option>
    <option value="7200">120 minutes</option>
</select> <span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="stopwatch(this);" />
```

Comment: The pause button completely stops the timer. Is there anyway to get a message saying the time was done?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one sir:

```
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;
var start_time;
function Countdown(start) {
    this.start_time = start === undefined ? "1:00" : start ;
    this.target_id = "#timer";
    this.name = "timer";
    start_time = this.start_time;
}

Countdown.prototype.init = function () {
    this.reset();
    ticker = setInterval(this.name + '.tick()', 1000);
}

Countdown.prototype.reset = function () {
    time = this.start_time.split(":");
    this.minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
    this.seconds = parseInt(time[1]);
    this.update_target();
}

Countdown.prototype.tick = function () {
    if (this.seconds > 0 || this.minutes > 0) {
        if (this.seconds == 0) {
            this.minutes = this.minutes - 1;
            this.seconds = 59
        } else {
            this.seconds = this.seconds - 1;
        }
    }
    this.update_target()
}

Countdown.prototype.update_target = function () {
    seconds = this.seconds;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    $(this.target_id).val(this.minutes + ":" + seconds)
}


var timer = new Countdown();
timer.init();


function start() {
    var s = document.getElementById("period").value;
    document.getElementById("period").disabled = true;
    startTimer(s);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
    timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
    document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "black";
    clearInterval(ticker);

    ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
    tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
        showTime(secs);
    } else {
        timeInSecs--;
        document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "You have exceeded your time by " + (hhmmss(Math.abs(timeInSecs)));
        document.getElementById("period").disabled = false;
    }
}

function showTime(secs) {
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    secs %= 3600;
    var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    secs %= 60;
    var result = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + ":" + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = result;
}

function stopwatch(btn) {
    if (btn.value == "Pause") {
        clearInterval(ticker);
        btn.value = "Resume";
    } else {
        btn.value = "Pause"
        var timer = new Countdown($('#timer').val());
        timer.init();
    }
}

function hhmmss(secs) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var mns = Math.floor(secs / 60) % 60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    if (hrs < 10) hrs = "0" + hrs;
    if (mns < 10) mns = "0" + mns;
    if (secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;
    return mns + " minutes " + secs + " seconds";
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/c6nqt9uy/4/)

I think it will be better if you will create clock object. See code(see Demo:[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/f9X6J/232/))